# SlowCheetah wap transform executes from visual studio but not from msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2012, slowcheetah

I have a MVC4 web application project with SlowCheetah NuGet package installed. In this project I have a xml file which I wish to transform (not Web.config). In the csproj file, the Item has TransformOnBuild set to true.  When I build the project from visual studio, the file gets transformed. If, however, I execute msbuild directly such as `msbuild.exe mysolution.sln` the file does not get transformed.

Looking at the SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets, the behavior of msbuild seems to make sense to me. For Web application projects the TransformAllFiles target is not included in the BuildDepends on property. Instead, it relies on hooks into the publishing pipeline.

What I do not understand, however, is how the transform happens when I build from visual studio. Furthermore, although the transform runs, there is no evidence in the build output, even at Detailed level.  If I add the following target to my web project, it also runs when building from visual studio (and not from msbuild), but produces no output.

```
<Target Name="DoStuff" AfterTargets="TransformAllFiles">
   <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)_Web.config" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)Web.configXXX" />   
   <Message Importance="high" Text="DoStuff completed"/>
</Target>
```

When I build the project from Visual Studio, I can see the results of the copy operation, but no message in the output, and no mention of the DoStuff target in the build log. Clearly the target is getting run, but there is no evidence of it in the build output. Can anyone explain this behavior?